# How to do download from html grid to excel or CVS file in my c# code

Tags: c#, html, .net, excel, download

I am writing a windows service that is supposed to act as a robot. 
it should go to a webpage and does some acitvities like logging on, and then pressing a button to take some records from other side.

now I am almost done with everything and records has been take from server.

but I don't know to download the records from HTML grid to a excel or CVS local file with c# and .net framework.
the question is: how to download from html grid to local file with .net framework
I am not using asp.net, it is just a windows service

Comment: actually records are available on my html document

Comment: What framework are you using to connect to the website?  Is there a button on the site to download the values in another format?

Comment: I am using awsoemium, there is button to export and there is a radio button that allows to choose between cvs and excel, but I am new and have no idea how i can find out what to do

Answer (score 0):

```
****on click of the button you can dowload the excel****       

 protected void btn_download_template(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str_FolderPath = "c:/Budget_Sample.xlsx";
            Response.ContentType = ContentType;
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(str_FolderPath));
            Response.WriteFile(str_FolderPath);
            Response.End();
        }
```